# Can you use "the" with proper names in the posessive case?

Tags: definite-articles

For example: can I say this is *the* Lady Mary's car or this is ___ Lady Mary's car?

Comment: Both are noun phrases.

Comment: The modern rule is that you can't use an article (a determiner) before a possessive modifier (also a determiner). Determiners usually work one to a noun phrase, preceding the adjective component, and if you've got a possessive, the article has nothing to determine.

Answer (score 2):

This use of the article [started falling into disuse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+Lady+Catherine%2Cof+the+Lady+Catherine&year_start=1719&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&case_insensitive=true) centuries ago, and there's been a *huge* shift towards the article-less form in the last couple of decades. You should only include the article today if you're trying to evoke "medieval" associations.

[image]

Note that ***the** Lady XXX* was only ever "valid" to refer to a ***titled*** woman (awarded the status ***Lady XXX*** by some recognised civic ceremony). You certainly wouldn't use it of a "commoner".